# Creating a very large list in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I have  list of object with me. These objects are called WordPairs.

Example: `((WordPair1) (WordPair2))` and so on. I have a function extract their confidence values. I want to create another list with their confidence values. That list will have only numbers. At the end of this computation, I will be having a list of numbers that correspond to the list of WordPairs. I know how to create a basic list using `cons`. The problem here is that I have 500,000 word pairs and with recursive cons I would run into stack overflow pretty fast.

What can be the solution?

My naive solution is this:

```
(define (create-conf-list lst)
(define wp (car lst))
(define confidence (tv-conf (cog-tv wp)))
(if (not (null? (cdr lst)))
    (cons confidence (create-conf-list (cdr lst)))
    '()))
```

How can this be improved?

P.S: I am running into a Stack Overflow with this approach. I need a more efficient approach. I cannot think of how to insert tail recursion here.

Comment: you use structure mutation to iteratively build a list in top-down manner, with the [head sentinel trick](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscheme%5D+head+sentinel) for convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like something you could do with "accumulate and reverse", since you want the result in the reverse order of what straight accumulation would produce:

```
  (define (helper ls acc)
    (define wp (car ls))
    (define confidence (tv-conf (cog-tv wp)))
    (if (null? (cdr ls))
        (reverse acc)
      (helper (cdr ls) (cons confidence acc))))
```

This is tail-recursive since the recursive case is only a call to the function itself - the result of the recursive call isn't used for anything else.
The reversal is needed because the `cons` in the accumulator builds the list in the reverse order.
(You might be tempted to use `(append acc (list confidence))` to keep the list in the wanted order, but the `append` makes it very slow.)

Then you can call it from the "actual" function:

```
(define (create-conf-list lst)
  (helper lst '()))
```

Or you can roll the functions into one:

```
(define (create-conf-list lst)
  (define (helper ls acc)
    (define wp (car ls))
    (define confidence (tv-conf (cog-tv wp)))
    (if (null? (cdr ls))
        (reverse acc)
      (helper (cdr ls) (cons confidence acc))))
  (helper lst '()))
```

Side note:
You're dropping the last element of the confidences, but since you're at the optimising stage I assume that's what you want.
If it's not what you want, you should fix that bug before you think about optimisation.

Comment: Sorry! I meant to check if list was null, not `(cdr lst)`

Comment: And how is this tail recursion? Could you explain the code please? I am unable to figure out the tail recursion in this.

Comment: What exactly is accumulation? Can you point me to some resource that explains accumulation?

Comment: @RohitShinde Any book on functional programming in general, and Scheme in particular, when they discuss tail recursion. If you have "SICP" - The Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs ([available for free online](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html)) - read the chapter concerning iterative processes. How to Design Programs ("HtDP") is also [available online](http://htdp.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Mapping a list onto a corresponding list of values via a function is usually done using map.

```
(define (get-confidence-values list-of-word-pairs)
  (map (lambda (wp) (tv-conf (cog-tv wp)))
       list-of-word-pairs))
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/10YDqG seems to show your approach is faster (probably because `map` is a built-in).

Comment: @WillNess 500,000 entities could cause a stack allocation issue if the stack frame is large. On the other hand if each object is 1000 bytes in size, that's still only half a gigabyte of allocation (or less than $1.00 worth of RAM). `map` is the sort of place where dropping down into C for implementation and using mutation internally for the sake of performance are probably reasonable.

Comment: @WillNess That's why using `map` is  "usually done". The other issue about "largeness" just takes time to get the hang of it's dependency on algorithmic efficiency. 30 is a lot if the algorithm has O(30!) and 2 million is nothing these days if the algorithm is O(n) as is the case when dealing with a list operation.